# GMSAutocompleteViewController want to get text which is in searchbar on search click

Tags: ios, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete

Hi i have used GMSAutocompleteViewController full-screen control.
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_ui_control

i am not able to get keyboard search click event tried by searchbar event and textfieldshouldreturn event but it is not called. i want to get text which i have typed when any location not found in google.

[image]

Comment: Have you initialized your own `UISearchController` and assigned, or simply used `GMSAutocompleteViewController`? If you are not using your own search bar, you won't be able to catch any searchbar event.

Comment: simply used GMSAutocompleteViewController.

Comment: Go through [this](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_search_bar_to_the_navigation_bar) section. You can access `UISearchController` delegate methods, and catch text for searchbar and other events.

Comment: @iAnum its not possible in full-screen control ? i have to use add results controller? http://screencast.com/t/MsSQV4I1

Comment: I am not sure... By looking at docs, it seems like you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Google Places API** documentation..

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_ui_control

> Use a results controller when you want more control over the text input UI

You can not access search bar if you are using `GMSAutocompleteViewController`. You have to use `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put your provideAPIKey.

Answer (score 0):

try removing restriction of the api from the console

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=.

it helped me.

thnx